# Xamarin SkiaSharp

Tags: xamarin, skiasharp

Try to use/learn SkiaSharp with this
[SkiaSharp-FormsSample](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/tree/master/samples/FormsSample).
But I can't compile it, because it uses SkiaSharp-Nuget-Packages 1.56.0, that are not available, so I can't deinstall the packages. Has anybody a solution or an idea, how to solve it?
Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

This is because sometimes the master branch moves ahead of the actual releases.

Typically, the latest releases (https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/releases) have the correct samples, so you can either download the `samples.zip` in the *Downloads* section, or navigate to that particular tag and check that out.

Basically, `master` is "unstable" and the tags are the stable versions - I accept PRs to master, and then when releasing, I tag.